# Flatten Layer ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_5: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, error-handling, conv-neural-network

I imported the following packages:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Reshape, Concatenate, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from keras.utils import Sequence
import efficientnet.keras as efn
```

I took the `EfficientNetB0` and excluded the top to use a customized one and I took the weights of `imagenet`.

```
efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False
```

And created the following model:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.3)(model)
    backbone = Flatten() (model)
    backbone = model
branches = []
for i in range(7):
        branches.append(backbone)
        branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
        branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
        branches[i] = Dropout(0.3)(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Dense(128, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
        branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
        branches[i] = Activation("relu")
        branches[i] = Dropout(0.3)(branches[i])            
        branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
    
output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
model = Model(input_img, output)

return model
```

When executing:

```
model = create_model()
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-834f03506210> in <module>()
----> 1 model = create_model()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    356                                      self.name + ': expected min_ndim=' +
    357                                      str(spec.min_ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
--> 358                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
    359             # Check dtype.
    360             if spec.dtype is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_5: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

It seems like the `Flatten()` layer is not compatible.. How should I amend my code? Without this layer I do not get this error.

**Edit:**

I modified the network and commented out some layers and now it works:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = Dropout(0.2)(model)
    #backbone = Flatten() (model)
    backbone = model

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])
            # branches[i] = Dense(128, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
            # branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
            # branches[i] = Activation("relu")
            # branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])            
            branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

return model
```

Maybe that could help to find an answer for the error I got at first...

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but, I think the problem is in the `output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)` statement.

I understand you want (7, 35) dimension output, but the error refers to the need for additional dimension.

Since I can't test the network, I think you can try with the statement:

`output = Reshape((1, 7, 35))(output)`

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the error..  update my question and show how it works now...